# Как отключить уровень логировния Debug при подключении кафки

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka

Есть вот такой код:

```
fun main() {

    val props = Properties()
    props[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "first-stream-app"
    props[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = Serdes.String().javaClass
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = Serdes.String().javaClass

    val builder = StreamsBuilder()
    val textLines: KStream<String, String> = builder
                    .stream<String, String>("streams-demo", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))

    fun getWords(line: String): List<String> =
            line.toLowerCase().split("\\W+".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
    val wordCounts: KTable<String, Long> = textLines
            .flatMapValues { textLine -> getWords(textLine) }
            .selectKey { _, value -> value }
            .groupByKey()
            .count(Materialized.`as`<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("counts-store"))
    wordCounts.toStream().to("streams-demo-out", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))

    val streams = KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props)
    streams.start()

}
```

При запуске получаю кучу логов в таком формате:

```
21:04:57.939 [first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=first-stream-app] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 32 to MetadataCache{cluster=Cluster(id = W4eDbi_qRD2udBrJu04BTA, nodes = [192.168.0.15:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = streams-demo, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = first-stream-app-counts-store-repartition, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = [])], controller = 192.168.0.15:9092 (id: 0 rack: null))}
21:04:58.039 [first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=first-stream-app] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=null, allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node 192.168.0.15:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
21:04:58.042 [first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=first-stream-app] Updating last seen epoch from 0 to 0 for partition streams-demo-0
21:04:58.042 [first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=first-stream-app] Updating last seen epoch from 0 to 0 for partition first-stream-app-counts-store-repartition-0
21:04:58.042 [first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=first-stream-app-1e30b3db-2237-4560-ac96-19af93aed5bb-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=first-stream-app] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 33 to MetadataCache{cluster=Cluster(id = W4eDbi_qRD2udBrJu04BTA, nodes = [192.168.0.15:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = streams-demo, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = first-stream-app-counts-store-repartition, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = [])], controller = 192.168.0.15:9092 (id: 0 rack: null))}
```

Как отключить написание `debug` логов?

Answer (score 0):

Просто настройте другой уровень логирования для `org.apache.kafka`. Поищите у себя в проекте файл `log4j2.xml` или `log4j2.properties`